# Is there a nice way create new Object with some parameters in its constructor and also to have CDI beans injected in it?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

```
Example:

@Dependant 
public class SomeStartingPoint {

@Inject
private SomeService someService;

   public void doSomething(Long aLong, MyCustomObject myObject) {
       NotABean notABean = new NotABean(aLong, myObject);
       someService.doStuffWithNotABean(notABean);
   }
}


public class NotABean {

@Inject
private WouldBePerfectIfThisWouldBeManagedBean somehowInjectedBean;

   public NotABean(Long aLong, MyCustomObject myObject) {
      //set state
   }
}
```

So the question is, is there a nice way to have something injected into the NotABean object, which supposed to have state in it, thus created by new()?

Of course, in current situtation I could pass WouldBePerfectIfThisWouldBeManagedBean as an argument to constructor, but this is not related to the question.

Comment: Perhaps you really want the CDI bean to be a factory that can combine injected and call-time parameters.

Comment: Are you using CDI 1.1 or 1.0?

Comment: 1.0. Does 1.1 has such feature?

Comment: It's a bit easier to do in 1.1.  I'll include both in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's a CDI 1.0 way and a CDI 1.1 way to do this.  The 1.1 way is much easier than 1.0, hence why they created it.

Here's an example from DeltaSpike: https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/34b713b41cc1a237cb128ac24207b76a6bb81d0c/deltaspike/core/api/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/provider/BeanProvider.java#L437

```
    CreationalContext<T> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);

    AnnotatedType<T> annotatedType = beanManager.createAnnotatedType((Class<T>) instance.getClass());
    InjectionTarget<T> injectionTarget = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(annotatedType);
    injectionTarget.inject(instance, creationalContext);
```

Assuming you have an instance of some object that has fields or methods annotated `@Inject` it will satisfy those dependencies.

In CDI 1.1, you can do the opposite.  Using the class `Unmanaged` you can instantiate unmanaged instances of your class.  You would need to call setters afterwards to set the values.

```
   Unmanaged<Foo> fooU = new Unmanaged(Foo.class);
   Foo foo = fooU.newInstance().get();
```

One other way, without using `@Inject` is to use the CDI 1.1 utility class to manually get references.  So instead of injecting a reference to `SomeService` you could do:

```
   SomeService someService = CDI.current().select(SomeService.class).get();
```